# JsonReader how to handle single item vs array

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using JSON .NET to parse the response that I receive from webservice.
The problem is that the response may contain single item, or multiple items(array),  which will cause the response string to be slightly different.

Single item response:

```
{
    "row": "1",
    "name": "John"
}
```

Multiple items response:

```
[
    {
        "row": "1",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "row": "2",
        "name": "Doe"
    },
]
```

I'm using the following code to parse

```
 List<MyClass> wsRetrieveDataResponse = JsonReadSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(reader);
```

The problem here is that since it is using `List<MyClass>`, it is expecting an array, and if the web service response is a single item, it will throw an error. How do I handle both cases?

[EDIT]: `JsonReadSerializer` has the type of `JsonSerializer`, which is part of JSON.NET. Deserialize is JSON.NET function.
I just add some constructor to handle some cases. Code as below.

```
public static JsonSerializer JsonReadSerializer;
```

Constructor for `JsonReadSerializer`

```
JsonReadSerializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    MissingMemberHandling = JSON_ENFORCE_MISSING ? MissingMemberHandling.Error : MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
    NullValueHandling = JSON_NULL_IGNORE ? NullValueHandling.Ignore : NullValueHandling.Include
 };
```

[EDIT #2]: My response is using type `JsonTextReader`

```
// Get the response.  
...
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

return new JsonTextReader(reader);
```

Comment: could you please show the `JsonReadSerializer` what your `Deserialize` method actually does?

Comment: added in [EDIT] above

Comment: And show also your `Deserialize` method inside `JsonReadSerializer`?

Comment: I don't have. It's a JSON.NET function.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the type of your json with `JTokenType` enum provided by `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

First of all try to load your `JToken` with `JsonTextReader` with `.Load` method provided by `JToken` and then check if parsed `JToken` is an `Array` or `Object`.

After that `JToken.ToObject<>` cast or map `JToken` to specified type that you want to.

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Load(reader);

if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    List<MyClass> wsRetrieveDataResponse = jToken.ToObject<List<MyClass>>();
}
else if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    MyClass wsRetrieveDataResponse = jToken.ToObject<MyClass>();
}
```

Comment: by the way, my response is stored in a `JsonTextReader`. I don't have it in `string`. How do I convert from `JsonTextReader` to jsonString ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use something of this sort:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(content);

if (token is JArray)
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> response= token.ToObject<List<MyClass>>();
}
else if (token is JObject)
{
    MyClass myClass= token.ToObject<MyClass>();
}
```